# Collection of generic objects not working as intended

Tags: java

I have my own generic class which goes like this:

```
C1<T> {
    T value;
    ...
    void setValue(T val) {
        this.avlue = val;
    }
}
```

Somewhere else i have this collection:

```
  List<C1> list;
```

Then in a different piece of code I instantiate some objects of type C1 like this:

```
C1<Integer> a;
C1<Float> b;
C1<String> c;
...
```

Later i put them in the list;

```
list.add(a);
list.add(b)
...
```

The next thing i do is this:
iterate over list doing this:

```
list.get(i).setValue(obj);
```

where obj is a variable of type Object which could be an Integer, Float, etc.

Now there problem is that is the instance of C1 returned from the list (lets call it c1) was defined like this:

```
C1<Type1>
```

Java will allow this:

```
c1.setValue(val2);
```

where val2 is of type Type2 and Type2 is not equal to Type1 and is not even in the same class hierarchy (except Object ofc)!

EDIT: 
Forgot to ask the question :)
How do i make setValue "Type safe" when accessed the way I'm doing it above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store objects of types `C1<Type1>` and `C1<Type2>` in a `List<C1>`, it is not possible to determine the exact type when you retrieve an element from the list. You will only know that it is a `C1` (as all elements in the list).

If you really need to ask the `C1` at runtime what its type parameter is, you need to store some type token in C1:

```
 C1<T> {
    private final Class<T> cls;

    C1(Class<T> pCls) {
      cls = pCls;
    }

    Class<?> getTypeParameter() {
      return cls;
    }
  }
```

Then you can call `getTypeParameter()` on the instance you got from the list and compare it to the type you expected.

Note that this will still allow you to store values of `Type2` in a `C1<Type1>` if you use an unchecked cast. If you want to eliminate this possibility, check the runtime type of `val` against `cls` in `setValue()` and throw an exception if they don't match.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining your collection as `List<C1>` so it will accept any object of type C1 regardless of how you parameterized that type. If you wanted to restrict it to only holding a specific kind of C1 you'd need to do `List<C1<Type1>>`

Comment: Well yes, I'm guessing that is the problem, but I want my collection to allow all C1's no matter what Type1 is (ie. Type1 is of type Object). I want this type to be resolved to what it really is at the time i access the members of the collection. I could probably do this with reflection, but that is kind of the last resort...

Comment: You can't have it both ways. If you want the collection to hold any kinds of C1 then you can't have the compiler ensure type safety at compile time. You're right that you can use reflection to check at run-time, though.